# node.js route design - refactor functions out to their own route or not?

Tags: node.js

I'm new to node.js. When designing which routes should be exposed... let's say you have an event route, with the standard GET, POST, PUT, DELETE. And, in your front-end app let's say you want to regularly update an event address. (One of many functions.) Should I sometimes refactor these functions out to their own route? For example, is it better to do something like a PUT to /event/:id and simply pass the new address? Or is it better to create a route like /eventaddress/:id (for a PUT)?

And, beyond this one example.... let's say I have a function to CalculateAverageAttendance or LinkPersonToEvent, etc... Should these be put in it's own route and exposed as an endpoint?

Comment: Doing `PUT to /event/:id` and then specifying which parameters you want to modify in the actual data itself (such as `{address: someAddress}`) is a lot more extensible and it lets a caller set more than one event parameter at once if so desired.  If you wanted to be more specific, I would prefer `PUT /event/:id/address`.  The noun is the `event` so that should be the top level name and the property is `address` so that should be a sub-identifier, not the main identifier.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks. Can you look at my revise original post and give me your thoughts? You can do it in such a way where I can give you credit for the answer too.

Comment: It's a bit hard to answer these without seeing the overall lay of the land of nouns, verbs and properties.  But I would think `GET /event/:id/calculateAverageAttendance`.  But, the decision about whether to expose it as an endpoint depends entirely upon whether you want that function in your API and whether the clients of the API need or want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `PUT /event/:id` and then specifying which parameters you want to modify in the actual data itself (such as `{address: someAddress}`) is a lot more extensible and it lets a caller set more than one event parameter at once if so desired.

If you wanted to be more specific with the route, I would prefer `PUT /event/:id/address`. The noun is the `event` so that should be the top level name and the property is address so that should be a sub-identifier, not the main identifier.

These kinds of questions are generally easier to answer when one can see the whole lay of the land (all the nouns, verbs and properties).

But I would think `GET /event/:id/calculateAverageAttendance` would be appropriate. But, the decision about whether to expose it as an endpoint depends entirely upon whether you want that function in your API and whether the clients of the API need or want it.

For something like `LinkPersonToEvent`, that would probably be `POST /event/:id/linkPerson` and put the person in the body data.  If a person is more like an attribute of an event, then this could be a PUT instead of a POST.

> And, in your front-end app let's say you want to regularly update an event address. (One of many functions.) Should I sometimes refactor these functions out to their own route?

If the front-end wants to regularly update something like an event address, then there should be an efficient route for doing that.  It doesn't have to be a route dedicated only for that function.  A more general purpose `PUT /event/:id` that lets you then specify which properties of the event you wish to modify works just fine and efficient for that too.